# Detecting if a string is a pangram in Python

Tags: python

How is this working?  It checks if a string contains each character from a-z at least once?

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):  
    alphaset = set(alphabet)  
    return alphaset <= set(str1.lower())
```

This returns True for example:

```
ispangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

I can only assume it is something to do with lexographical ordering as stated here, but still a bit confused.

[Comparing two lists using the greater than or less than operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator)

When I read the link in this SO question:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types

It says:

> Sequence objects may be compared to other objects with the same
>   sequence type. The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the
>   first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the
>   outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are
>   compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted. If two items
>   to be compared are themselves sequences of the same type, the
>   lexicographical comparison is carried out recursively. If all items of
>   two sequences compare equal, the sequences are considered equal. If
>   one sequence is an initial sub-sequence of the other, the shorter
>   sequence is the smaller (lesser) one. Lexicographical ordering for
>   strings uses the Unicode code point number to order individual
>   characters. Some examples of comparisons between sequences of the same
>   type.

But this isn't clear to me.

Comment: Did you read: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset ?

Comment: I have now, thanks @alfasin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a `set` operation, not `list`. Which is equivalent to,

```
alphaset.issubset(set(str1.lower()))
```

> s <= t
>
> s.issubset(t)
>
> Test whether every element in s is in t.

See here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

**Edit:** See here for the current version of [Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). Though easier explanation is given in the old version (For comparisons).

Comment: `s.issubset(t)` is equivalent to `s <= t` see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset

Comment: No idea why this got downvoted.  This is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful - not surprised I was confused

Answer (score 2):

No. It's comparing two [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set). So it's converting the input string to lower case and then using Python's set type to compare it with the set of lowercase letters.

This is very useful (and fast) technique for comparing two lists to see what members they have in common/difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pangram(s):
alphabet = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
s = s.replace(' ','').lower()
s= sorted(s)

count = {}

    #alphabet could be one sting within '' later sorted, but I just went straight to the point. 
    #After initializing my dictionary at null, we start the count    

for letter in s:
    if letter in count:
        count[letter] =[]
    else:
        count[letter] = 1

for letter in alphabet:
    if letter in count:
        count[letter] =[]
    else:
        count[letter] = 0
for letter in count:
    if count[letter]== 0:
        print (letter +' missing!')
print (count[letter]!= 0)
```