# Compare list of tuples, confirm subset based on condition?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counter

Given a word and a list of words, I have to find the list elements/words that can be built using letters (count of letter matters) of the given word. I have tried to use `Counter` object from collections and a definition of python 2.7's `cmp()` function (I'm using 3.6.5).

I have since come to realize this approach seems to be bad practice for such a problem (Earlier, I was trying to use counter object-dictionaries to compare). The reason my program doesn't work is because the compare_fn relies on '>','<' operations between lists, which give result based on lexicographical order ([referred from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator)). So even though 'raven' can be made from 'ravenous', the program below will fail because of the order of char in a sorted list.

```
from collections import Counter    
word = 'ravenous'
candidates = ["raven", "mealwheel", "rasputin"]

def count_fn(mystr):
    return sorted(list(Counter(mystr).items()))

def compare_fn (c1,c2):
    return ((c1>c2) - (c1<c2))

list_word =  count_fn(word)
list_candidates = list(map(count_fn,candidates))
cmp_list = [compare_fn(list_word,i) for i in list_candidates]
cmp_list
#[-1, -1, -1]    #should be [1,-1,-1]
```

So, for below two lists, how can I confirm that `list_candidates[0]` is a subset of `list_word`. Please note that the comparison `('a',1)` in `list_word` against `('a',1)` in `list_candidates[i]` could also be `('a',5)` in `list_word` against `('a',1)` in `list_candidates[i]` ; both cases are true.

```
print(list_word)
#[('a', 1), ('e', 1), ('n', 1), ('o', 1), ('r', 1), ('s', 1), ('u', 1), ('v', 1)]
print(list_candidates[0])
#[('a', 1), ('e', 1), ('n', 1), ('r', 1), ('v', 1)]
```

Comment: What happens `('a', 1)` is in `list_word` and `('a', 2)` is in `list_candidates` ?

Comment: Related question: [Find all letters of a string in another string](//stackoverflow.com/q/49975213)

Comment: @BcK, it will be False. Example - I can't make 'Rusts' from 'rustify' (need two s) ; but I can make 'Ub' from 'Buu' (one extra U)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using counters is a good choice. Don't turn them into lists.
I purposely returned [True, False, False] instead of [1, -1, -1], but you can change that easily.

Moreover: I used a list comprehension instead of map, beacause it is more current in python, but the semantic is the same.

```
from collections import Counter
word = 'ravenous'
candidates = ["raven", "mealwheel", "rasputin"]

def count_fn(mystr):
    return Counter(mystr)

def compare_fn (c1,c2):
    return all(c1[char] >= count for char, count in c2.items())

counter_word =  count_fn(word)
list_candidates = [count_fn(candidate) for candidate in candidates]
cmp_list = [compare_fn(counter_word, i) for i in list_candidates]
print(cmp_list)
```

Comment: You could alternatively define `compare_fn` as `c2 - c1 == {}`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey , I had used help(Counter) and came across c2-c1 in the documentation. from what I understand, if the counter element is an exact match, the result won't show. "difference stripping away all negative and zero counts" . So, if the words compared are anagrams, then it won't be in the result. I was earlier going to ask on SO, how to return zero count instances in c2-c1. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Aran-Fey from help (collections.Counter)  - 
 
>>> Counter('bccd') - Counter('bccd')
 |      Counter()         // how does empty counter become True?

Comment: @Poppinyoshi `Counter` is a dict subclass, so comparing an empty counter to an empty dict returns `True`. But you have to use `==`, not `|`.