# How to determine best poker hand kicker (equality of lists in python)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a program that allows users to play poker (for fake money, don't come after me IRS), and had a problem trying to determine kickers for better hands. So initially my thought was to sort the values of the cards (without suits) which I have like `[14, 12, 10, 8, 6]` (with 14 for ace high). And compare it to another list, say `[14, 12, 10, 8, 7]` (7 kicker) to see which ranks higher. Each hand comes from one of the 5 card combinations from the 7 available cards in a hold 'em game. My initial thought was to do:

```
def better_hand_with_kicker(list0, list1):
    for index in range(5):
        if list0[index] >= list1[index]:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Yet, this won't work if **any** number was smaller. For instance between `[14, 12, 10, 8, 6]` and `[14, 13, 9, 7, 5]` it will return that `[14, 12, 10, 8, 6]` is superior because even though (13 > 12) makes the other hand win, the third slot of (9 < 10) will trigger the `return False` clause.

Therefore I thought of a slightly more complex:

```
def better_hand_with_kicker(list0, list1):
    for index in range(5):
        if list0[index] == list1[index]:
            continue
        elif list0[index] > list1[index]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return True # this would really be a tie
```

Now this works, but I figure there must be a much more elegant solution...

Comment: In general, to iterate two or more iterable in parallel, use `zip`, not `range`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 That's a good idea, I always seem to forget about `zip`...

Answer (score 1):

There was a much more elegant solution! After searching the web for ideas about inequalities between lists and finding [this amazing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator) I realized that my solution was incredibly inadequate. The best solution would be to use:

```
def better_hand_with_kicker(list0, list1):
    if list0 > list1:
        return True
    return False
```

This uses the fact that an inequality of a list will evaluate similarly to the other function I created, specifically:

> The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

The caveat is that each list must be `sorted()` prior to this inequality evaluation. Hopefully this post helps somebody in the future trying to use inequalities on lists of integers. In my use-case this is so much more condensed, it turned an entire function I was writing into a single `if` statement that I no longer truly need a function for! Now my code can simply be:

```
if list0 > list1:
    # do stuff
```

With no function necessary. I'm not sure why online tutorials don't seem to cover this feature...Anyways,

Praise be to StackOverflow!

Comment: This can be simplified to `return list0 > list1`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Yes, that's what I meant by " it turned an entire function I was writing into a single `if` statement. I edited it to be more clear now, thank you for the comment!