# Matplotlib fill_between function not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please see the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

to_utility = [-3.4000000000000004, -2.6999999999999993, -0.9000000000000004, 1.8000000000000007, -1.0999999999999996,
              -1.6999999999999993, 0.6999999999999993, 5.300000000000001, 0.1999999999999993, 2.3999999999999986, 2.5,
              1.3999999999999986, -3.6999999999999993, -8.8, -6.600000000000001, -9.600000000000001, -11,
              -7.800000000000001, -8.4, -8.9, -11.7, -7.300000000000001, -8.9, -4.9]

shifted = 6.652632153034208

curve_max = max(to_utility)
curve_min = min(to_utility)

upper_shift_line = [curve_max - shifted] * len(to_utility)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title('To Utility Curve')
ax1.set_ylim([curve_min, curve_max])
ax1.plot(range(len(to_utility)), to_utility, upper_shift_line)
ax1.fill_between(range(len(to_utility)), to_utility, upper_shift_line, where=to_utility > upper_shift_line,
                 interpolate=True)
plt.show()
```

Somehow the area is not filled, but if I remove the where= condition, it will work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator. This is not actually what you want. But rather you want to compare element-wise `[a > b for a,b in zip(A,B)]`

Comment: Thanks! The element-wise compare worked!