# Why is [5, 6, 9] < [5, 7] True?

Tags: python

Why is `[5, 6, 9] < [5, 7]` True?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two lists using the greater than or less than operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator)

Comment: @UnholySheep the first element of the first list IS NOT LESS THAN the first element of the second list so why is it true?

Comment: ... so what about the second element?

Comment: That is literally answered in the linked question, so I'm not sure what your comment is about

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons

> Sequences compare lexicographically using comparison of corresponding
> elements. The built-in containers typically assume identical objects
> are equal to themselves. That lets them bypass equality tests for
> identical objects to improve performance and to maintain their
> internal invariants.
>
> Lexicographical comparison between built-in collections works as
> follows:
>
> For two collections to compare equal, they must be of the same type,
> have the same length, and each pair of corresponding elements must
> compare equal (for example, [1,2] == (1,2) is false because the type
> is not the same).
>
> Collections that support order comparison are ordered the same as
> their first unequal elements (for example, [1,2,x] <= [1,2,y] has the
> same value as x <= y). If a corresponding element does not exist, the
> shorter collection is ordered first (for example, [1,2] < [1,2,3] is
> true).