# Get last sunday of month - python

Tags: python

I have a question about 2 lines of code - from my thinking point of view it should be the same, but i get different outputs for those 2 lines.

Can someone explain me why?

```
max(week[-1] for week in calendar.monthcalendar(year,month))
max(calendar.monthcalendar(year,month)[-1])
```

year = 2021 and month = 3

For the first line I get the right output 28th which was the sunday. For the second line I get 31, which basically just is the last number.
week[-1] from monthcalendar should be the last array or not? Which in this case would be [29,30,31,0,0,0,0] so the max from it should be 31

```
max(week for week in calendar.monthcalender(year,month))
max(week[-1] for week in calendar.monthcalendar(year,month))
```

Also this 2 lines - the first gives me an array [29,30,31,0,0,0,0] and the second gives me a single number 28 and I don't get why? shouldnt the first return 31 and the second 28?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to review parts of the data to see what is going on:

The first `max(week[-1] for week in calendar.monthcalendar(year,month))` loops over the week lists of the calendar. The output of the for loop is: `7, 14, 21, 28, 0`: printing each last day of the week. Hence `max` returns `28` as it is the max of this.

The second `max(calendar.monthcalendar(year,month)[-1])` takes the last week of the month `[29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Hence `max` returns `31`.

The third `max(week for week in calendar.monthcalender(year,month))` gives the biggest list of the monthcalendar. See [Comparing two lists using the greater than or less than operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator) why the last list is returned.

The fourth is the same as the first.