# How to use boolean on list correctly?

Tags: python, list, boolean

```
def check(A,B,a,b):
    return A >= a and B >= b

A = [500, 500, 500]
a = [20, 0, 0]
B = [5, 5, 5, 5]
b = [0, 10, 0, 0]

print(check(A, B, a, b))
```

(result True)

I want result become False if only one in list A or B have small value than a or b. In this code B[1] < b[1] (5 >= 10) result I expect is False but is output True

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two lists using the greater than or less than operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two
> items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of
> the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared,
> and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

---

To get `False` in your example, you can use built-in `all()` to compare all values in arrays:

```
def check(A, B, a, b):
    return all(x >= y for x, y in zip(A, a)) and all(x >= y for x, y in zip(B, b))


A = [500, 500, 500]
a = [20, 0, 0]
B = [5, 5, 5, 5]
b = [0, 10, 0, 0]

print(check(A, B, a, b))
```

Prints:

```
False
```